# Manually change the cell that phone is connected to

Tags: android

Is it possible to change the cell which your smartphone is connected to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is impossible.

Device changes the Cell which is camped via 2 mechanisms:

- Cell Re-selection
- Handover

**Cell Reselection**

This mechanism enable the device to find a better cell to register. Basically, phone remains measuring signal level of different cells, frequencies and RAT (2G/3G/4G) and it can then, select an suitable cell.

Since phone choose the best cell, re-selection is possible only when device is in IDLE (IDLE means that no resources are allocated to your device.. there's no DATA Traffic / Call ongoing etc).

Each MODEM vendor has implemented its own Algorithm to decide the most suitable cell but usually, thy always try to move your device to LTE and to the cell with strongest signal level.

**HANDOVER**

This mechanism allow the phone to move to a better cell while it is on service (during a call or during data traffic). Since you have resources allocated to you, this is fully controlled by network (only network knows if target cell can receive your device and keep delivering the service that you are using).

**This is just overview**

This is just the basic idea of what happens in Modem side. Even in case of re-selection, a lot of parameters are controlled by network (such as "Start to measure a better cell if the signal level falls below a certain level" etc).

Most important is that you can not manually control it... You can force your device to 2G/3G or LTE. Even then, MODEM side will decide the better cell to you (based on carrier settings for that location) and you can not control it...

Also, each chipset (modem) vendor has its own implementation for this...

Some chipset vendors are Qualcom, Infineon, Marvell, Spreadtrum, Broadcom (RIP)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. if you allow me, do you know how to get the list of neighbors cell towers (and get their ids) because both telephonymanager.getallcellinfo() and getNeighboringCellInfo() have problems

Comment: Hummm. Sorry Oussama... I can not help you with those methods... I don't use to work with them... SO, I'm not aware of them :(

Comment: It is okay, have a nice day!

Comment: is there any standard documentation provided by any vendor on this ?